# How to retrieve stats for dynamic templates via Sendgrid API

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm looking for help on how to retrieve stats for dynamic templates via SG API using curl.

Using https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates?generations=dynamic I've been able to get

specific template info but I can't seem to successfully use the dynamic template_id

and version id or subject id to pull stats for each email under the main template_id.

I get success returns for all stats using https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/stats?start_date=2022-05-01

but when I try to add template_id or any other param it's ignored by the API.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation for the global email statistics API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/stats/retrieve-global-email-statistics) the available query parameters that you can provide are:

- `limit`
- `offset`
- `aggregated_by` - can be "day", "week" or "month"
- `start_date` - as you used in your example
- `end_date`

You cannot filter by the template, version or subject.

Comment: That's what I thought but was hoping there was another way. Thanks for taking the time to confirm - very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer did help, please do mark it as correct so that others can see it was useful too. Thanks!